# Processing: How do I make a triggered sound stop?

Tags: audio, processing

When the picture of the woman moves over one of the moving hexagons, a few things happen. I have a sound(police) that is triggered when she touches one of them. The problem is that the sound continues even when she is not on the hexagon even longer. Plus, if she touches the hexagon again the sound is triggered again over the first sound. So now I have a mess of the same sound playing over each other.

I want her to move over a hexagon, the sound is triggered. When she moves off the hexagon the sound instantly stops until she moves over it again.
Here's the code:

```js
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
Minim minim;
AudioSample police;
color underhex = color(255, 0, 0);

PImage woman;

float headX = 50, headY = 50;
float ss = 0;
float fade=30, fade2=9;

PShape hexagon, trapezoid, trapezoid2;
float[] hspeed = {2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4, 4.4, 4.8};
float[] g = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void setup() {
  size(900, 600, P3D);
  background(250);
  noStroke();
  minim = new Minim(this);
  police = minim.loadSample("PoliceSiren.mp3", 1024);

  hexagon = createShape(GROUP);
  PShape trapezoid = createShape(QUAD, 100, 50, 325, 50, 375, 180, 50, 180);
  PShape trapezoid2 = createShape(QUAD, 50, 180, 375, 180, 325, 320, 100, 320);
  hexagon.scale(0.25);
  hexagon.addChild(trapezoid);
  hexagon.addChild(trapezoid2);
  hexagon.setFill(color(255, 0, 0, 50));

  woman = loadImage("woman.png");
}

void draw() {
  background(250);

  image(woman, headX, headY, 70, 81);

  for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(g[p], 120*p);

    underhex = get(int(g[p])+30, int(120*p)+30);

    shape(hexagon, 0, 0);
    //ellipse(width/2,height/2,50,50);
    popMatrix();
    g[p]+=hspeed[p];

    if (int(g[p]) > 830 || int(g[p]) < 0) {
      hspeed[p] *= -1;
    }

    if (red(underhex) < 20 && green(underhex) < 20 && blue(underhex) < 20) {
      println("she's here"+random(5));
      fill(0, 240);
      rect(0, 0, 900, 600);
      strokeWeight(30);
      fill(0, 0, 255, fade);
      stroke(0, 0, 255, fade);
      ellipse(250, 200, 100, 100);

      fill(255, 0, 0, fade);
      stroke(255, 0, 0, fade);
      ellipse(290, 330, 100, 100);

      fill(0, 0, 255, fade);
      stroke(0, 0, 255, fade);
      ellipse(680, 200, 100, 100);

      fill(255, 0, 0, fade);
      stroke(255, 0, 0, fade);
      ellipse(640, 330, 100, 100);
      noStroke();
      police.trigger();
      fade += fade2;
      if (fade<0 || fade>255) {
        fade2 *= -1;
      }
    }
  }

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      headY-=random(2, 6);
    } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      headY+=random(2, 6);
    } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      headX-=random(2, 6);
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      headX+=random(2, 6);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AudioPlayer` instead of `AudioSample`. It provides [isPlaying()](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/ddf/minim/AudioPlayer.html#isPlaying--) which is handy to check if the sound is already playing or not.
e.g.

```
//at the top
AudioPlayer police;
//in setup()
police = minim.loadFile("PoliceSiren.mp3");
//in draw() instead of police.trigger()
if(!police.isPlaying() || ){
   police.play();
}
```

**Update**

It sounds like looping is what you're after:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
Minim minim;
AudioPlayer police;
color underhex = color(255, 0, 0);

PImage woman;

float headX = 50, headY = 50;
float ss = 0;
float fade=30, fade2=9;

PShape hexagon, trapezoid, trapezoid2;
float[] hspeed = {2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4, 4.4, 4.8};
float[] g = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void setup() {
  size(900, 600, P3D);
  background(250);
  noStroke();
  minim = new Minim(this);
  //police = minim.loadSample("PoliceSiren.mp3", 1024);
  police = minim.loadFile("PoliceSiren.mp3");

  hexagon = createShape(GROUP);
  PShape trapezoid = createShape(QUAD, 100, 50, 325, 50, 375, 180, 50, 180);
  PShape trapezoid2 = createShape(QUAD, 50, 180, 375, 180, 325, 320, 100, 320);
  hexagon.scale(0.25);
  hexagon.addChild(trapezoid);
  hexagon.addChild(trapezoid2);
  hexagon.setFill(color(255, 0, 0, 50));

  woman = loadImage("woman.png");
}

void draw() {
  background(250);

  image(woman, headX, headY, 70, 81);

  for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(g[p], 120*p);

    underhex = get(int(g[p])+30, int(120*p)+30);

    shape(hexagon, 0, 0);
    //ellipse(width/2,height/2,50,50);
    popMatrix();
    g[p]+=hspeed[p];

    if (int(g[p]) > 830 || int(g[p]) < 0) {
      hspeed[p] *= -1;
    }

    if (red(underhex) < 20 && green(underhex) < 20 && blue(underhex) < 20) {
      println("she's here"+random(5));
      fill(0, 240);
      rect(0, 0, 900, 600);
      strokeWeight(30);
      fill(0, 0, 255, fade);
      stroke(0, 0, 255, fade);
      ellipse(250, 200, 100, 100);

      fill(255, 0, 0, fade);
      stroke(255, 0, 0, fade);
      ellipse(290, 330, 100, 100);

      fill(0, 0, 255, fade);
      stroke(0, 0, 255, fade);
      ellipse(680, 200, 100, 100);

      fill(255, 0, 0, fade);
      stroke(255, 0, 0, fade);
      ellipse(640, 330, 100, 100);
      noStroke();
      if(!police.isPlaying()){
        police.loop();
      }
      fade += fade2;
      if (fade<0 || fade>255) {
        fade2 *= -1;
      }
    }else{
      if(police.isLooping()){
        police.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      headY-=random(2, 6);
    } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      headY+=random(2, 6);
    } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      headX-=random(2, 6);
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      headX+=random(2, 6);
    }
  }
}
```

Also checkout `mute()`,`unmute()`,`isMuted()`: perhaps you can keep the sound looping but muted and only unmute when the collision happens

Comment: This stops the sound from playing over each other, but it does not stop playing when the woman is no longer near the hexagons. It just continues playing until the sound is over and I can't activate it again.

Comment: @ebonydoa In addition to George's answer, you also need to write code that detects when the woman moves off of the hexagon. You've got code that detects when she moves onto it, so presumably you'd be able to check for the opposite. The trick will be detecting the change from being over it to moving off of it. Then you need to cancel the sound playing when you detect that case.

Comment: I have been at this for hours and the only thing that seems to work is the mute and unmute. But when I use that my sound comes out glitchy with cuts. I've tried to get rid of the glitch by lower and rising the buffer size, but that seems to do nothing.

Comment: @ebonydoa I've slightly updated the answer, turns out ```isLooping()``` isn't as useful in your situation, use ```isPlaying()``` instead: the idea is the same though: if the condition to play the sound(hit test) passes, check if the player is playing, if not loop, otheriwse, if the hit test condition isn't met, ```pause()``` or ```rewind()``` the player as needed. Same logic, but on mouse press instead of the collision: ```if(mousePressed){
    if(!police.isPlaying()){
        police.loop();
      }
  }else{
    if(police.isPlaying()){
      police.rewind();
    }
  }```